# Optimizing Code for Project Euler Problem 04

Tags: java, beginner, palindrome

I just finished Problem 04 on Project Euler, and I was looking at ways to optimize my code, just started learning functions too, so I'm pretty sure it's very bad, hopefully you guys can help me.

***Question***

**A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.**

**Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.**

```
public class TestProblem10 {
    public static int checkPalindrome(int a, int b){
        boolean palindro = false;

        if (a % 1000000 / 100000 == a % 10 && a % 100000 / 10000 == a % 100 / 10 &&
                a % 10000 / 1000 == a % 1000 / 100) {               // Checking if it's a palidrome
            if (a > b) {         // Making sure to return the largest palindrome possible.
                b = a;           // A = MULT B = PALINDROME
                palindro = true;
            }
        }
        if (palindro){
            return b;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

> I do not like very much the 5th and the 6th line because it took so much space, if there's one way to make it better do let me know too please.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // var
        int palindrome = 0;

        // processing
        for (int i = 900; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int k = 900; k < 1000; k++) {
                int mult = (i * k);
                if (checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome) == 0){
                    continue;           // Won't let the result = 0 when func returns 0
                }else{
                    palindrome = checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome);
                }
            }
        }
        // out
        System.out.print("Largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers is " + palindrome);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Arithmetic simplification

```
if (a % 1000000 / 100000 == a % 10 && a % 100000 / 10000 == a % 100 / 10 &&
        a % 10000 / 1000 == a % 1000 / 100) {
```

An expression like `a % 10...0 / 100` can be simplified to `a / 100 % 10`. So the whole condition becomes:

```
if (a / 100000 % 10 == a % 10 && a / 10000 % 10 == a / 10 % 10 &&
        a / 1000 % 10 == a / 100 % 10) {
```

### Search range

```
for (int i = 900; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int k = 900; k < 1000; k++) {
```

How do you know you'll find a palindromic product with `i` and `k` in the range [900, 1000); did you prove that?

How do you know that if you search `i` and `k` in the range [100, 1000), you won't find a bigger palindrome? (For example, pretend that 900×900=810000 is the biggest palindrome in the first case but 899×1000=899000 is the biggest palindrome in the second case.)

Absent a proof, the conservatively correct thing to do is to search the entire 3-digit range given by the problem:

```
for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int k = 100; k < 1000; k++) {
```

### Extra parentheses

```
int mult = (i * k);
```

For this simple expression, it's clearer to not use parentheses:

```
int mult = i * k;
```

### Common subexpression and control flow

```
if (checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome) == 0){
    continue;           // Won't let the result = 0 when func returns 0
}else{
    palindrome = checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome);
}
```

Store the function result to avoid calling it twice, saving time and code:

```
int temp = checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome);
if (temp == 0){
    continue;           // Won't let the result = 0 when func returns 0
}else{
    palindrome = temp;
}
```

Furthermore, change the if-continue to just a negative if:

```
int temp = checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome);
if (temp != 0){
    palindrome = temp;
}
```

### Mixed concerns

Your function `checkPalindrome()` basically behaves like:

```
if (isPalindrome(a) && a > b)
    return b;
else
    return 0;
```

It's a weird function because it tests palindromes, figures out a maximum, or returns the special sentinel value of 0. I would advocate for writing a pure `isPalindrome()` Boolean function, and putting the maximum check in `main()` instead.

### Access modifier

```
    public static int checkPalindrome(int a, int b){
```

The function doesn't need to be called from outside the class, so set it to `private`.

### Full revised code

```
public class TestProblem10 {
    private static int checkPalindrome(int a, int b){
        boolean palindro = false;

        if (a / 100000 % 10 == a % 10 && a / 10000 % 10 == a % 100 / 10 &&
                a / 1000 % 10 == a / 100 % 10) {               // Checking if it's a palidrome
            if (a > b) {         // Making sure to return the largest palindrome possible.
                b = a;           // A = MULT B = PALINDROME
                palindro = true;
            }
        }
        if (palindro){
            return b;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // var
        int palindrome = 0;

        // processing
        for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int k = 100; k < 1000; k++) {
                int mult = i * k;
                int temp = checkPalindrome(mult, palindrome)
                if (temp != 0){
                    palindrome = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        // out
        System.out.print("Largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers is " + palindrome);
    }
}
```

### My solution

Feel free to read my [p004.java](https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions/blob/c5adb3ddd8f8b430d073564a7a6c2e8d117a360d/java/p004.java?ts=4#L17-L31) and [Library.java](https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions/blob/c5adb3ddd8f8b430d073564a7a6c2e8d117a360d/java/Library.java#L14-L29). A preview:

```
int maxPalin = -1;
for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 100; j < 1000; j++) {
        int prod = i * j;
        if (Library.isPalindrome(prod) && prod > maxPalin)
            maxPalin = prod;
    }
}
return Integer.toString(maxPalin);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, also, why did you used ```Integer.toString``` ?

Comment: I used `Integer.toString()` because it converts the number to a base-10 string, and it can handle any length palindrome. Your function `checkPalindrome()` only works correctly for 6-digit numbers. Actually, 100 × 100 = 10000 which is a 5-digit number, so there's a new bug in the program.